# get EXTRA_CALL_DISCONNECT_CAUSE after call ended

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephony

I'm making an Android app which need to monitor when the call is disconnected and get the disconnect cause to do some more things. I'm using a broadcast receiver to know when the call is disconnected but I'm stuck at getting the disconnect cause.

Below is my brief code:

```
    final BroadcastReceiver phoneStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String state = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            String cause = null;
            if (intent.hasExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CALL_DISCONNECT_CAUSE)) {
                cause = intent.getExtras().getString(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CALL_DISCONNECT_CAUSE);
            }

            TextView callState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.callState);
            callState.setText("Call State is: " + state + " " + number + " " + cause);
        }
    };

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerReceiver(phoneStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED));

            btnStop.setEnabled(true);
            btnStart.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            unregisterReceiver(phoneStateReceiver);

            btnStart.setEnabled(true);
            btnStop.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

Please, somebody helps me at this point?
Many thanks.!!!

Answer (score 2):

From API-21 documentation, [EXTRA_CALL_DISCONNECT_CAUSE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html#EXTRA_CALL_DISCONNECT_CAUSE) & [EXTRA_CALL_DISCONNECT_MESSAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html#EXTRA_CALL_DISCONNECT_MESSAGE) are optional extras for TelecomManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED. Looks like they do not have any data in them in AOSP code and as observed on Nexus 5 (L & M releases). It has been left for OEMs to implement and report any data in those extras. I am looking for any devices that use these extras. It would be great to know of any devices which do report call disconnect cause / message.